# my header is multiline--within the multiline i require alignment of the two dots--how to do it?

Tags: header

[image]

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} \fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt} 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.1pt} 
\fancyhead[C]{
    \footnotesize Quality Management System Manual \ ISO 9001:2015 \         Controllerate of Quality Assurance \ Armoured Vehicle Electronics\Avadi, Chennai – 600 054} 
\fancyhead[R]{\footnotesize Document: Level 01\ Issue No: 01 \ Issue Date: 15 Sep 2019 \ Rev No/ Rev Date: --- \ Page: \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
\fancyfoot[L]{\footnotesize Prepared in \LaTeX\ Typeset By\ Colonel JS Bibra\ Joint Controller\ Management Representative }
\fancyfoot[R]{\footnotesize Verified \&\ Approved for Issue By\ S Satish Chandra Kumar\ Controller\ CQA(AVL) } %\fancyfoot[L]{\footnotesize Verified By\ %& should have \ %J Peter\ %PScO\ %Deputy Controller % }
\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics{../../images/"dgqa logo".png} %\caption{DGQA Logo} \label{DGQA Logo} }
```

Comment: how does one put an image of the output file in the forum?

Comment: The toolbar of the edit window has a small icon looking like a mountain (6th from the left)..

Comment: can i use tabs in the header as done in ms-word

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: haha-its not on purpose believe me--if someone could point me in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The horizontal alignment around the colon `:` is possible if you set the heading using a `tabular`:

[image]

```
\fancyhead[R]{%
  \footnotesize
  \begin{tabular}{@{} r @{:\ } l @{}}
            Document & Level 01    \\
            Issue No & 01          \\
          Issue Date & 15 Sep 2019 \\
    Rev No/ Rev Date & ---         \\
                Page & X of XX
  \end{tabular}}
```

Comment: Thanks. Request breakdown the following line.  \begin{tabular}{@{} r @{:\ } l @{}}

Comment: works perfect thanks

Comment: why does the bracket start on the first line --\fancyhead[R]{%--and not on the second line?

Comment: how is the alignment carried out for all the 4 lines while coding-- Document & Level 01    \\
            Issue No & 01          \\
          Issue Date & 15 Sep 2019 \\
    Rev No/ Rev Date & ---         \\
                Page & X of XX

Comment: but now the header is misaligned --image above

Comment: @jsbibra. Put both the `R`ight and `C` header in their own `tabular`. That way they'll be vertically aligned in the centre.

Comment: The alignment is done using two columns in the `tabular`. The left column defined the "label" and the right the "value" associated with that label. You can change the alignment to be `l`eft, `r`ight or `c`entre. The column separation is given by `@{:\ }` which prints a `:` followed by a space for each row. The outer `@{}` removes any column spacing, thereby pushing the `tabular` flush to the `R`ight side of the page/header.

Comment: how is the alignment carried out for all the 4 lines while coding

Comment: @jsbibra: The alignment is given in the column specification: `..r..l..` means two columns; first is `r`ight-aligned and the second is `l`eft-aligned.

Comment: sorry if i was not clear --i meant the code at the top in the grey area is very neatly aligned--how is it done--i did not mean the output part of the code but the code itself for example-- Document  & Level 01   \\--are all aligned in the four lines of code --how is it done--hope i am clear

Comment: @jsbibra: Oh, I just spaced it out manually, because it made the code presentation clear; that is, the horizontal alignment in the output matched the code (input). It's just a preference. There is a package - [`latexindent`](//ctan.org/pkg/latexindent) - that does this kind of thing, if you're interested. I don't think it'll perform an alignment that matches the output, but it'll align on your typical alignment characters, like `&` and ``\\``.

Comment: @jsbibra: You can delete your own comments.